# how to store text starting with '+' in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to store value like +a1.2.0 in excel cell but after storing it appears as #NAME?
If I double click on it, then only the content appears. If I directly open the excel I should see the content not #NAME?. I am not able to produce it. Any suggestions?

I think this #NAME? appears because of formula it automatically created because of '+' sign before the content.

Comment: Format your cells to text first or I guess you could try a single apostrophe in front of your value, e.g.: `'+a1.2.0`

Comment: @JvdV I tried using single apostrophe, it appears +a1.2.0 but the content changed to '+a1.2.0, when i double click the cell it appears '+a1.2.0. The content should be same, in this case if i add single apostrophe, the content itself is changed. And the cells are already formatted as text

Comment: Then use the first option I mentioned. Format the cells prior to adding values.

Answer (score 2):

You may write apostrophe ' before or change the format from General to Text.